# How to predict matching between two objects?

Tags: prediction, matching

There is information from a website which connects questions from users to suitable professionals that might be interested in answering the particular questions.

The data contains over 10.000 previously posted questions. Most questions have 1 or 2 answers, a few up till 30 answers. Both the answers and questions have attributes like 'likes', 'hashtags', date and time attributes. Further there are attributes to the users that posted the question and the users (professionals) that answered it: date of joining, profession, interests, groups joined, previous emails with suggested questions received (for professionals).

The professionals get new open questions to daily and weekly emails, and groups and hashtags they follow. All this information is available.

My goal is to predict for each answer whether a specific professional would be interested in answering it.

Is there a mathematical way to approach such a problem? I'm not really sure where to start. For each unique question and answer there are only a couple of observations. Basically there are many professionals, but usually only one or two which answered a particular question.

For example, should questions be clustered first based on similarity?

EDIT 16/04: someone suggested collaborative filtering and I'll look into that.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is rather unclear. It would help, I think, to get less abstract and tell us exactly what these objects, attributes and observations are.